# FIFO queue structure based on a singly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

In the java course I'm following right now, I'm required to implement a FIFO queue structure based on a singly linked list. I have to implement interface and override 3 methods: add, poll and peek.

I'm stuck with poll and peek and can **not get an Object** in return statement. Or may be there is another way to do it. For any help would be very grateful.

**add** -Use add() method to add elements into the Queue
**poll** - Fetching and removing the element at the head of the    queue
**peek**- as pool without removing

```
public class Queue<T> implements Queue2<T> {

    Node<T> head;
    Node<T> tail;
    int size;

    @Override
    public boolean add(T e) {

        Node<T> node = new Node(e);

        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
            tail = node;
        } else {

            tail.next = node;
            tail = node;
            node.next = null;
        }
        size++;
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public T poll() {
        if (size == 0)
            return null;
        else {
            T obj = head.getObject();
            head = head.next;
            if (head == null) {
                tail = null;
            }
            size--;

            return obj;
        }

    }

    @Override

    public T peek() {
        if (head == null)
            return null;
        else {

            return head.getObject();

        }
    }


    class Node<T> {
        Node<T> next;

        Node<T> value;

        public <T> Node(T value) {


        }

        public T getObject() {
            **return null;** // what should be returned here?
        }
    }
}
```

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<String> queue1 = new Queue<>();
        queue1.add("finns");
        queue1.add("bella");
        queue1.add("ssara");
        queue1.add("nanna");
        queue1.add("anna");
       System.out.println(queue1.peek());
       System.out.println(queue1.poll());
```

Comment: "can not get an Object in return statement": Please explain.

Comment: My guess is that `getObject` should return the value that the node is initialized with, ie in your example strings such as "finns", "bella" etc. Also, you might want to reconsider whether the `value` field should actually be a `Node` or whether it should be the generic type T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Node<T> {
    Node<T> next;
    T value;
    public Node(T value) {
        this.value=value;
    }

    public T getObject() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The value in Node is your object so should be of type `T` , not `Node<T>`.

Remove the `<T>` from the constructor otherwise you are defining a new T and the assignment `this.value=value;` will not work.

Comment: ahhhhh, those mistakes) Thanks!